# Apache AirFlow installed on remote centos server is not accessible from local

Tags: airflow

I have installed Apache AirFlow on centos and started the webserver. I can see the service is up and running on the port but when i am trying to access from local but url is not accessible. I have disable the firewall on the server and i am able to access other services installed on the serer from my local except AirFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting the question, It was due to port blocked by firewall. Thanks for all the help.